# Alternative to deprecated pd.Series().convert_objects(convert_numeric = true), able to parse string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

I wonder if an alternative to `pandas.Series(x).convert_objects(convert_numeric = true)` exists for the following case:

```
px = dt.ix[:,1] # pandas.core.series.Series
pmat = pd.Series(px).convert_objects(convert_numeric = True) # works but convert_objects is deprecated in future version
```

In case further information on the data might help, please note that:

```
dt:Type = DataFrame, size=(1790,2), Value= column names: 0,1
px: Type=Series, size=(1790,), Value= class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```

So far I've tried as a way around following some searches:

```
pmat = px.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
pmat = pd.to_numeric(px) # Unable to parse string
```

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) which works with `Series` (column of `df`):

```
#invalid parsing will be set as NaN
pmat = pd.to_numeric(px, errors='coerce')
```

Or:

```
#invalid parsing will return the input
pmat = pd.to_numeric(px, errors='ignore')
```

Also `ix` [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), better is use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your promptness on this. Best